# Why required not working in vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

You can see my case below

My vue component is like this :

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control" :name="elementName" v-model="selected" :required="module === 'addProduct'" >
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        props: ['elementName', 'module'],
        data() {
            return {
                selected: 'Choose'
            };
        },
        ...
    };
</script>
```

The result is like this :

[image]

I don't select anything. I click button submit, the required not working. It not display the required

I try like this :

```
<option value="">Choose</option>
```

It works. But, when accessed first time, option choose not show

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See their example: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

It doesn't display anything because you have: `selected: 'Choose'` but you have no `option` with **value="Choose"**. (the value is the *empty string*, "Choose" is just the inner text of the option element).

Try this:

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control" :name="elementName" v-model="selected" :required="module === 'addProduct'" >
        <option disabled value="">Choose</option>
        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        props: ['elementName', 'module'],
        data() {
            return {
                selected: ''
            };
        },
        ...
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I want the "choose" not disable. Because my component used by another module

Comment: You can just remove the `disabled` attribute. Setting the 'selected' observable to `''` will select the placeholder `Choose` option.